# Removing last character in python for loop

Tags: python

I am attempting to make a python script that prints out a multiplication table for two inputted integers. I'm pretty much done but I have a small formatting issue that I am having trouble resolving. This is what it outputs currently:

```
Start of table 27
End of table 33
        |    27 |    28 |    29 |    30 |    31 |    32 |    33 

    27  |   729 :   756 :   783 :   810 :   837 :   864 :   891 :
    28  |   756 :   784 :   812 :   840 :   868 :   896 :   924 :
    29  |   783 :   812 :   841 :   870 :   899 :   928 :   957 :
    30  |   810 :   840 :   870 :   900 :   930 :   960 :   990 :
    31  |   837 :   868 :   899 :   930 :   961 :   992 :  1023 :
    32  |   864 :   896 :   928 :   960 :   992 :  1024 :  1056 :
    33  |   891 :   924 :   957 :   990 :  1023 :  1056 :  1089 :
```

As you can see in the image each row in the table has a ":" after each integer. This is from this for loop:

```
for i in range(start,end+1):
    print("%5d  |"%i,end="")
    for j in range(start,end+1):
        print("%6d"%(i*j),":",end="")
    print()
```

As you can see in line 4, I have the string ":" which adds the colon after each integer. The problem is I don't want it to add it on the last number for every row. How do I solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to paste program output in a code block (as I have edited to show) instead of as a link to an image to allow for improved accessibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try utilising `str.join()` to insert your separator between values:

```
for i in range(start, end+1):
    print("%5d  |"%i,end="")
    row = ["%6d "%(i*j) for j in range(start,end+1)]
    print(':'.join(row))
```

This method saves you having to write extra code to handle the last case differently.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(start,end+1):
    print("%5d  |"%i,end="")
    for j in range(start,end):
        print("%6d"%(i*j),":",end="")
    print("%6d" % (i * end))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take the last one out of the loop :

```
for i in range(start,end+1):
    print("%5d  |"%i,end="")
    for j in range(start,end):
        print("%6d"%(i*j),":",end="")
    print("%6d"%(i*end))
```

Answer (score 0):

You must verify in the second if the iteration is equal to the last one, if so, the separated variable is cleaned:

```
for i in range(start,end+1):
    print("%5d  |"%i)
    for j in range(start,end+1):
        separation = ":"        
        if j == end:
            separation = ""
        print("%6d"%(i*j),separation)
    print()
```